# Socket.IO Handshake Secure Flag Always False

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want my sockets to communicate securely.  I think I'm requesting communication over https.  So why is the secure flag always false?  I've tried a bunch of different flag settings with no effect so far.

Sample site developed on glitch.com here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sponge-tablecloth.

Landing page is here: https://sponge-tablecloth.glitch.me/

Client page code:

```
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  socket = io("https://sponge-tablecloth.glitch.me/");
  socket.on('message', function(message) { div.innerHTML += message + "<br>"; });
</script>
```

Node.js server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

let io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("checking connection, secure: " + socket.handshake.secure);
  io.emit('message', "checking a connection, secure: " + socket.handshake.secure);
});

let listener = http.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `io("https://....` with `io("wss://...")` ?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I tried that.  No change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is most likely that a reverse proxy is terminating TLS before proxying the requests to your application. It is common to have a setup that looks like this:

```
User -[HTTPS]-> Nginx(terminate TLS) -[HTTP]-> Application
```

This means that your application thinks that the transport was always insecure, while in fact it's just been terminated by the proxy (in this case Nginx). Glitch.io likely does this exact thing since your application is only offering insecure HTTP connections.
If you want end-to-end encryption you need to use the `https` package from stdlib instead of the `http` package, and setup certificates.